# Facing problem while moving svg polygon to center on click

Tags: javascript, dictionary, svg, gsap

I have an SVG image which is made up to multiple polygons. When I click on any of the polygons then that polygon will come up in the center after moving the whole SVG image automatically.

I have tried tweenmax library for this and here is the code snippet :

```
jQuery('[data-name^="retailer_"]').on('click', function (event) {   

        var ActiveFloorValue = jQuery('#mapit-floors-filters a.active').attr('data-floor-index');

        jQuery('polygon').attr("class","");
        var map_store_name = jQuery(this).data('name');         
        jQuery('#mapit-floor-'+ActiveFloorValue+ ' svg').attr('id','svg-'+ActiveFloorValue);

        var main1x = document.getElementById('mapit-floor-'+ActiveFloorValue);


        TweenLite.to( main1x, 0, { ease: Linear.easeOut, clearProps:"scale"});
        TweenMax.to(main1x, 1.5, {
                scale: 1.9,
                x:-event.clientX/2 ,
                y:-event.clientY/2 ,                  
                ease:Linear.easeOut,
                transformOrigin:"center center"                
                })

    });
```

So please help me to make it possible. I hope you understand my question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the link :

Comment: http://demo.insonix.com/tony-word/map/